# For loop in javascript to catch multiples of 200

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this code which checks the margin-left of the navigation, and scrolls it left accordingly. However, this method is slow, so I would like to know how to change it into a for loop or something of the sort to catch every multiple of 200 then animate the navigation accordingly.
This is my code currently, as you can tell not very efficient if this needs to go up to -5000 ect.
**EDIT**
These are my functions, but they do not work

```
    function goleft(){
    var nav = $("#innernavigation");
    var navmargin = parseInt(nav.css("margin-left"), 10);
    if (navmargin != 0)
    {
        //time!
        if (navmargin > -nav.width() && navmargin < -200)
        {   
            nav.animate({'marginLeft':'-' + ((Math.floor(navmargin / 200)-1) * 200) + 'px'});
        }
        if (navmargin > 0)
        {
            nav.css({'marginLeft':'0px'});
        }
    }
}
function goright(){
    var nav = $("#innernavigation");
    var navmargin = parseInt(nav.css("margin-left"), 10);
    if (navmargin != -nav.width())
    {
        //time!
        if (navmargin > 0 && navmargin < -nav.width())
        {   
            nav.animate({'marginLeft':'-' + ((Math.floor(navmargin / 200)-1) * 200) + 'px'});
        }
        if (navmargin < -nav.width())
        {
            nav.css({'marginLeft':'-' + nav.width()});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in single if statement.

```
if (navmargin > -5000 && navmargin < -200)
{
    nav.animate({'marginLeft': (-((Math.floor(navmargin / 200)-1) * 200) + 'px'});
}
```

Comment: Except without the `if`.  This only does `>-200` and ignores everything else.

Comment: Thanks James, what about if we have check on upper limit, for instance 5000?

Comment: That's better.  Though I have a hunch the -5000 was just an example and there is no need for an upper limit.

Comment: @Adil, how could I change this code to make it go right instead of left? And btw -5000 was an example, what i meant was -nav.width() i think (so if nav.width is 5000 it equals -5000). If you can help me with a statement to navigate right I will accept. thankyou

Comment: You will probably need to reverse the condition like if (navmargin < 5000 && navmargin > 200) nav.animate({'marginLeft': (+((Math.floor(navmargin / 200)-1) * 200) + 'px'});

Comment: @Adil ok, can you please see my revised question because I cant get these codes to work

Answer (score 0):

```
nav.animate({'marginLeft': (Math.floor(Math.abs(navmargin) / 200) * -200) + 'px'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a fast guess (not tested yet):

```
if (navmargin<-200 && navmargin>-5000) {
    nav.animate({'marginLeft':((navmargin%200-1)*-200)+'px'});
}
```